# how to switch between tkinter frames

Tags: python, tkinter

so I'm having trouble switching between Tkinter frames so what I have created right now is a login screen
After pressing the login button they are taken to a different frame where they type in their credentials and there is a back button to take them back to the home screen

so essentially my code is

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Project 1')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 500))
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
def back():
     #here the frame created in login is forgot and homescreen is called 
     screen_2.grid_forget() # forgets the frame created in login
     homescreen() # calls frames created in homescreen
def login():
     #here I make Tkinter forget the previous 2 frames and create a new one and add a back button to it
     top_frame.grid_forget()
     center.grid_forget()
     screen_2=Frame(root, bg="white", height=500, width=500, pady=3, padx=3)
     screen_2.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")
     back_bt=Button(text="back", bg="#40A2BF", fg="white")
     back_bt.grid(row=0, column=0) 
def homescreen():
     #here there are two frames a heading frame with the name of the app
     #the body frame with the login button
     login_bt=Button(center, bg="white", fg="black", text="Login", height=3, width=25, command=login)     
     login_bt.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

and before entering the credentials if the user wants to go back to the homepage they should press the back button which calls homepage again i think it is being called but the second frame is still hiding it
however, my problem is that I cant see the homepage again
Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: The `back` button inside `login()` did not configure `command` option, so clicking the button does nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry i fixed that in the code but it still didn't do anything i think that my problem lies in the commands issued in the back function

Comment: Based on posted code, you should get `screen_2` undefined error when `back()` is executed.  So better post a [mre].

Comment: You have created `back_bt` in root window instead of `screen_2`.

Comment: thank you so much my code worked after I placed back_bt in screen_2